# Why I saw 2 different screen in Project properties?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 projects.

I open them both.

And I got totally 2 different screen if I go to menu and click properties.

One is what I am familiar with.

I can easily change the start up form using drop down menu.[image]

Another, I have no idea

Another project looks like this

[image]

Why?

Comment: One is a project properties and the other is a solution (collection of projects) properties

Comment: That's an answer. Would you turn that to an answer because, well, I spend hours figuring this out. I already suspected that actually.

Answer (score 0):

One is a project properties and the other is a solution (collection of projects) properties. So, there are not two different project properties pages.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio) might be helpful MSDN content to help better figure see the differences and uses.